# Passing C# DateTime to SQL Server stored procedure as DateTime parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am passing `{4/1/2017 12:00:00 AM}` from my C# code to SQL Server as a parameter of a stored procedure. And in the stored procedure, I want to convert this into `MMddyyyy` format for data processing. I tried many suggestions from Google but nothing works for me.

Throwing this error:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Comment: How you are passing the values from c#, is it possible to include the code?'

Comment: First of all, why do you `want to convert to MMddyyyy in SQL for data processing?` Can't you compare DateTime with another DateTime?

Comment: @Un - lucky -- Please find the code
objSqlParameter[1] = new SqlParameter("@Startdate", Startdate)

Comment: @Nikhil -- There is a requirement to store that date in two tables. One table has DateTime datatype and another has varchar datatype.

Comment: Best case would be to change the varchar one to DateTime then. Will save a lot of work for you.

Comment: @Nikhil -- I can't change existing table schema since that is used by many.

Answer (score 0):

Try Convert keyword in SQL but should pass some param value (101,107) for convert.